# One time conditional print

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to build a conditional statement in Google Sheets. The statement should check for a certain value in a cell against other values in other cells until the first time it is met. Once met once it will print a certain text in another cell. Let me give an example:

Cell C1 has live data.
Cell D1 has one condition.
Cell E1 has another condition.
Cell F1 is blank.

Now the condition will look to match C1 with D1 and E1 until one condition is met and a text is printed on F1. Once F1 is not blank anymore the condition stops.

Comment: Someone please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem. But I do just combine IF function with OR. OR checks if at least one condition is met.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for bothering to reply.
I am already using this statement :-
=if(C3>=D3,"ABV",if(C3<=E3,"BLW","-")).

But the problem is Column C has live streaming data. As I mentioned above.
I only want the comparison to run until the first time it is met. Otherwise the result will keeping gyrating between Above and Below based on streaming data.

Hope I am clear now.

Comment: I understand your problem now. I don't know how to do it with a formula. I can imagine a script to do achieve it. A while loop that constantly checks the values and when the condition is met it sets a value ABV or BLW and breaks from the loop. However I don't know how to do it in Google Script.... Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Even I thought that I need to use Script, but I dont know how to use it. Anyway thank you for trying to help. Will wait for some help.